# Get object by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building what I think to be slightly complicated, but I have realized it doesn't work the way I would like to to, so I am here.

The following is an example of what I am doing.

```
ITEM1: {
  prop1: 'desc1',
  prop2: 'desc2',
},
ITEM2: {
  prop1: 'desc1',
  prop2: {
    SUBITEM1: {
      prop1: 'desc1',
      prop2: 'desc2',
      prop3: 'desc3'
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this works perfectly if I do the following

```
ITEM2.prop2.SUBITEM1.prop1;
```

The problem is I can not do `ITEM2.prop2.SUBITEM1` I need to do it in the following manner

```
ITEM2.prop2["SUBITEM1"].prop1
```

The project is still young, so if it that whole list needs to be rebuilt to do this properly, I don't mind.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What's the problem? ITEM2.prop2["SUBITEM1"].prop1 should work fine

Comment: Have you actually tried it? `ITEM2.prop2.SUBITEM1` is exactly equivalent to `ITEM2.prop2["SUBITEM1"]`. You could even do `ITEM2["prop2"]["SUBITEM1"] if you wanted.

Comment: I found the problem. Really NOOB mistake... I forgot to trim the string so it was trying to do `ITEM2.prop2[" SUBITEM1"].`

Comment: @Robert That will be undefined because that is not an array.

Comment: @Jai It's javascript we are talking about here...

Comment: I realized that now... So sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Of course I figure it out seconds after I post this, after spending an hour trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did you actually try? It works as such in Chrome. Screenshot for your info...

[image]

Textual Representation:

```
ITEM1= {
  prop1: 'desc1',
  prop2: 'desc2',
},
ITEM2= {
  prop1: 'desc1',
  prop2: {
    SUBITEM1: {
      prop1: 'desc1',
      prop2: 'desc2',
      prop3: 'desc3'
    }
  }
}
Object
ITEM2.prop2.SUBITEM1.prop1;
"desc1"
ITEM2.prop2["SUBITEM1"].prop1
"desc1"
```

Comment: Thank you! Will accept as soon as I can. Can't believe I was forgetting to remove the space...

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your answer before. You replaced the `ITEM1:`  with `ITEM1=`, just like I did. That's why it worked. So, it's not "as such".

Comment: Yeah. Even I faced the same syntax error! :P

Comment: Well I forgot to add the top level which was `options = {}` That was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want separate objects? I guess you missing the `var` keywords. In that case, you also have to remove an extra comma you have there. Try this:

```
var ITEM1 = {
  prop1: 'desc1',
  prop2: 'desc2',
};
var ITEM2 = {
  prop1: 'desc1',
  prop2: {
    SUBITEM1: {
      prop1: 'desc1',
      prop2: 'desc2',
      prop3: 'desc3'
    }
  }
};
console.log(ITEM2.prop2.SUBITEM1.prop1); // Works!
```

Comment: Er... It works without `var`.

Comment: Not with that comma. The code in the OP is invalid syntax.

Comment: If you are talking about the comma after `'desc2'` in ITEM1, it will cause problems in IE. I forget which version it is fixed in though. I think it is a problem in IE7 and maybe 8 as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar What makes you say that? Check http://jsfiddle.net/tHtWa/. Or did you wrap the whole thing in another object? That would work too.

Comment: code is valid and actually works as I want it to. I just forgot to remove the spaces. My code was looking for `ITEM2.pro2[" SUBITEM1"].prop1` Well there is no " SUBITEM2"

Comment: @ascii-lime Not just that, I mean `something : {}` is not valid syntax to start with. `var x = {something : {}}` would be ok.

Comment: I have the rare ability where I dont have to worry about IE. This web app is only every going to be run on a linux computer using chrome or firefox! Webdesign is so much more fun when you dont have to program for IE. ahha

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh So it means you didn't post the whole code, just part of an object. The code you posted does not work as is (see the jsfiddle link some comments above).

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh Good point about IE! IE sucks to the core! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes I left out the very top level sorry. The top level is `options = { }` Sorry